# message driven bean questions

Tags: jms, ejb-3.0

I have a list of stores with both Incoming and Outgoing Failed Message Queues. It uses Message Driven Beans (to read and write) into those Queues (Java Message Service(JMS) in `WildFly 8.0`)

I want to know

1. how to pinpoint (from the application) how and where these messages are written into the Queues
2. how to reduce the number of failed messages to a minimum

Comment: What is a Failed Message Queue?

Answer (score 0):

Messages fail because they timeout, increase the timetolive config value to avoid the messages ending up in the error queue.

To answer your first question, I dont have a specific answer, you may have to use logging statements just before you send the message to the queue along with the time. If your message has time also, later in the future you can cross verify the logs to that of the error messages.